# SQL Server removing null values

Tags: sql-server

Wanted help in the SQL below is my code

```
CREATE VIEW OpenPO_DIM (Sales_Line, Dim_ID, EMP, BT, RC, DIV)
AS
    SELECT  dbo.[ $Sales Line].[Document No_], --SL.no
            dbo.[ $Dimension Set Entry].[Dimension Set ID], --Dim_ID
            (SELECT       
                CASE
                    WHEN [ $Dimension Set Entry].[Dimension Code] = 'EMP' 

                    THEN [ $Dimension Value].Name 
                END 
            ), --EMP
            (SELECT       
                CASE
                    WHEN [ $Dimension Set Entry].[Dimension Code] = 'BT' 

                    THEN [ $Dimension Value].Name 
                END 
            ), --BT
            (SELECT       
                CASE
                    WHEN [ $Dimension Set Entry].[Dimension Code] = 'RC' 

                    THEN [ $Dimension Value].Name 
                END 
            ), --RC     
            (SELECT       
                CASE
                    WHEN [ $Dimension Set Entry].[Dimension Code] = 'DIV' 

                    THEN [ $Dimension Value].Name 
                END 
            ) --DIV

    FROM   dbo.[ $Dimension Value] 
            INNER JOIN dbo.[ $Dimension Set Entry] 
            ON dbo.[ $Dimension Value].[Dimension Code] = dbo.[ $Dimension Set Entry].[Dimension Code] 
            AND dbo.[ $Dimension Value].Code = dbo.[ $Dimension Set Entry].[Dimension Value Code]
            INNER JOIN dbo.[ $Sales Line] 
            ON dbo.[ $Dimension Set Entry].[Dimension Set ID] = dbo.[ $Sales Line].[Dimension Set ID]
    where  dbo.[ $Sales Line].[Document No_] LIKE N'%EG-SO%'
```

and I'm getting the output as seen in the screenshot below

[image: Output]

where I want the results to be returned like below:

[image: Required Result]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply .. any idea where i can include Group By clause with MAX

Comment: Why are they even coming in on different rows? This smells like a data problem to be honest. @HoneyBadger is right, that will (probably) help the issue at hand, however, it may not solve the long term problem, if the data is indeed stored poorly.

Comment: You can simply use PIVOT.

Comment: @CetinBasoz i thought of using Pivot before asking the question here.. but i didn't know how to use it.

Comment: @CetinBasoz How do i use Pivot with my Query

Comment: I added a sample as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE
(
    DocumentNo INT,
    SetId INT,
    DimCode VARCHAR(10),
    DimValue VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT @sample
(
    DocumentNo,
    SetId,
    DimCode,
    DimValue
)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'EMP', 'EMPName1'),
(1, 1, 'BT', 'BTName1'),
(1, 1, 'RC', 'RCName1'),
(1, 1, 'DIV', 'DIVName1'),
(2, 1, 'EMP', 'EMPName2'),
(2, 1, 'BT', 'BTName2'),
(2, 1, 'RC', 'RCName2'),
(2, 1, 'DIV', 'DIVName2'),
(3, 1, 'EMP', 'EMPName3'),
(3, 1, 'BT', 'BTName3'),
(3, 1, 'RC', 'RCName3'),
(3, 1, 'DIV', 'DIVName3'),
(4, 1, 'EMP', 'EMPName4'),
(4, 1, 'BT', 'BTName4'),
(4, 1, 'RC', 'RCName4'),
(4, 1, 'DIV', 'DIVName4');

SELECT *
FROM @sample
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(DimValue)
        FOR [DimCode] IN ([EMP], [BT], [RC], [DIV])
    ) pvt;
```

Comment: I tried your solution .. didn't work still i'm getting the same result

Comment: @Puneeth, apparently you didn't try mine but an edited version of mine :) Just copy & paste to studio and you would see that it works. Another approach might be cross\outer apply (might be easier too). Wish you provided sample data to play with as code.